# how to use array in for loop powershell

Tags: sql, powershell

Hi I am working on a ps script to backup sql database but i have 3 for loop to backup 3 database is there a way where i have  1 for loop which takes 3 variable which i have declared and do the backup. Here is my code

## Loads Assembly

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo") | Out-
Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoEnum") | Out-Null

$server = New-Object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server") "(local)"


 $bkdir = "C:\_DBbackups" #We define the folder path as a variable 
 $test1 = 'admin'
 $test2 = 'contacts'
 $test3 = 'humanResource'
 $dbs = $server.Databases



  foreach ($db in $dbs) 
  {
 
 
   if($db.Name -like $test1) 
    {
    $dbname = $db.Name
    $dt = get-date -format yyyyMMddHHmmss #We use this to create a file name based on the 
    timestamp
    $dbBackup = new-object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Backup")
    $dbBackup.Action = "Database"
    $dbBackup.Database = $dbname
    $dbBackup.Devices.AddDevice($bkdir + "\" + $dbname + "_db_" + $dt + ".bak", "File")
    $dbBackup.SqlBackup($server) 
    write-host "Database backup is successful for"$dbname 
    write-host "New Backup file is"$dbname"_db_"$dt".bak" 
    write-host "New Backup Location is" $bkdir
 
    }

    }
```

Can i also accomplish this with a single if statement like this

```
      if($db.Name -like $test1) or ($db.Name -like $test2) or ($db.Name -like  
      $test3) 
      {
        $dbname = $db.Name
        $dt = get-date -format yyyyMMddHHmmss 
        $dbBackup = new-object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Backup")
        $dbBackup.Action = "Database"
        $dbBackup.Database = $dbname
        $dbBackup.Devices.AddDevice($bkdir + "\" + $dbname + "_db_" + $dt + ".bak", "File")
        $dbBackup.SqlBackup($server) 
        write-host "Database backup is successful for"$dbname 
        write-host "New Backup file is"$dbname"_db_"$dt".bak" 
        write-host "New Backup Location is" $bkdir
     }
```

Comment: i want my for loop to have test1 variable taken in 1st than test 2 and than test3. At the moment i have 3 for loop where i manually enter 3 variable and it backs up the database

Comment: Do you want to add another loop, to loop across the 3 tests? where are you using the $test1, $test2 and $test3 variables in the code?

Comment: i am using in if statement

Comment: i can get this working if i have 1 loop and 3 if statement with in that loop. but is there any other way to get this working

Comment: I can't find anywhere where you are using $test.. are you referring to $Russia121V3?

Comment: Ok, just try the below answer and let us know if it works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this;

```
$array = @("admin", "contacts", "humanResource")
foreach ($element in $array) {
 foreach ($db in $dbs) 
   {

    if($db.Name -like $element) 
    {
    $dbname = $db.Name
    $dt = get-date -format yyyyMMddHHmmss #We use this to create a file name based on the 
    timestamp
    $dbBackup = new-object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Backup")
    $dbBackup.Action = "Database"
    $dbBackup.Database = $dbname
    $dbBackup.Devices.AddDevice($bkdir + "\" + $dbname + "_db_" + $dt + ".bak", "File")
    $dbBackup.SqlBackup($server) 
    write-host "Database backup is successful for "$dbname 
    write-host "New Backup file is "$dbname"_db_"$dt".bak" 
    write-host "New Backup Location is " $bkdir

    }
   }
  }
```

Comment: i edited the question..can i accomplish the same with single if statement as shown in my question

Comment: Then you won't need a loop i guess?

Comment: getting this error when i use or with if statement Missing statement block after if ( condition ).

Comment: Try `If (($db.Name -eq $test1) -or ($db.Name -eq $test2) -or ($db.Name -eq $test3)) { .. }`

Comment: still getting error Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.

Comment: check your brackets well, you may be missing one or having one more closing bracket than necessary.